# Seperate python environment per model in TorchServe

Tags: python, torchserve

Can TorchServe run seperate python environments for each model in TorchServe?

I have 4 models in production right now, and they all use `transformers==3.1.0` package.
A new model about to be put in production uses `transformers==4.25.1`.

Can the same TorchServe instance host all these models?

Looking at TorchServe docs, I have come across [install_py_dep_per_model](https://pytorch.org/serve/configuration.html) parameter, but I think this is used for installing dependencies globally. Current project installes dependencies right in the docker image, so I have not used this parameter before.

Answer (score 0):

As of now , there's no way for model specific package and I don't think there will be.
https://pytorch.org/serve/configuration.html
One running instance of Torchserve reads from only one PYTHONPATH.

As this is the concern of the environ you are running in , not the serving solution, i.e Torchserve.
Use a Venv or docker instead!